Are amplitude (AM) and phase (PM) noise truly unambiguous?
I've been reading a lot on phase noise and phase detection techniques, especially IQ detection. In the literature, it is made clear that phase fluctuations $\varphi(t)$ and (fractional) amplitude fluctuations $a(t)$ are separate phenomena,
$$v(t) = V_0 (1 + a(t)) \cos(\omega_0 t + \varphi(t)),$$
which can be combined in additive noise,
$$v(t) = V_0 \cos(\omega_0 t) + n(t),$$
but additive noise can also be separated into amplitude and phase noise terms (e.g. by separation into orthogonal components in the polar coordinate system).
What I'm struggling to wrap my head around is how we can truly discriminate both experimentally. When observing a noisy sinusoidal waveform, how can we tell whether the distortion is due to amplitude or phase modulation?
When employing some assumption as $a(t) \ll 1$, it can be argued that in the zero crossing, all noise has to be due to $\varphi(t)$, however we would then only be able to truly measure this at discrete points in time, whereas IQ demodulation is continuous.

I've tried to visualize my conceptual pitfall

whereas in the Phasor diagram, there is exactly one error vector from the reference point to the measured point, which can be decomposed into phase and amplitude mismatch, the same does not seem to be true for the time plot, where the measured point can be reached either via an amplitude scaling or a phase shift.


but additive noise can also be separated into amplitude and phase noise terms (e.g. by separation into orthogonal components in the polar coordinate system).

Be careful there! Assuming you do a, say 15° phase shift for an original point with amplitude 1, that means a very different additive noise term than if you do the same phase shift at an amplitude of 0.01.
The decomposition of noise into a phase and an amplitude component must happen at the point that was received, not when you are only considering the difference between what you received and what was sent.
Essentially, thinking of separable phase and amplitude noise mostly makes sense in multiplicative models.

What I'm struggling to wrap my head around is how we can truly discriminate both experimentally. When observing a noisy sinusoidal waveform, how can we tell whether the distortion is due to amplitude or phase modulation?

You estimate frequency, amplitude and phase of your sine wave, and then for each point in time, you look for the factor between the value that the "ideal" sine wave would have had, and what you observed. Then you get argument and magnitude of that.
This is easier if you think of complex sinusoids than if you think of real-valued sines. In the complex plane, a phase shift is just a multiplication with a $e^{j\varphi_{\text{shift}}}$.

The key point for me was the "ideal" sine wave you were referencing. In order to find the "error vector" on the phasor, it requires some reference with defined phase. Only then, phase and amplitude can be truly discriminated 360°.

@Xaser but that's true for any kind of error measurement. You can't say what the error is without knowing properties of the truth.

I'm again confused. I've updated my original post with a diagram visualizing my conundrum.
